# Floating UIButton on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton

I want to implement the following behaviour in my app:
I have a `UIScrollView` on my view with customizable `contentSize` and I want to put a `UIButton` in its bottom left corner to stay there when I scroll the view I want the button to stay exactly where it was, with the contents of the scroll view scrolling at the same time.

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you use Interface Builder/Storyboard? 
If so then just add the scroll view. Then add the Button but do not add the button as subview of the scroll view. Just add it as a sibling. But make sure that the scroll view comes first. The hierarchy should look like this:

```
\--View  (The underlaying UIView
    \--scrollView (The UIScrollView)
        \-- anyView (Any subviews of the scroll view come here
    \--button (The UIButton)
```

By doing so the button is independent from the scroll view, its scrolling or content size. It may well be placed over the scroll view.

Edit: A quick one (not syntax checked etc.) as example for a programmatic solution.

```
UIScrollView *myScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWith...];
UIImageView *someImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWith...]; //Just a sample subivew. 
UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWith...]; //Another sample.
UIButton *myButton [[UIButton alloc] initWith...]; 

[self.view addSubView:myScroller];
[myScroller addSubView:someImage];
[self.view addSubView:myButton]; //it is important, that myScroller was added first
[myScroller addSubView:someLable]; //the sequence of addding subviews to the content does not matter much.
```

(You may want to have a single content view within your scroller view which is then a container for all the subivews. But that does not affect what I try to explain.)

Comment: I don't use IB or XIBs unfortunately ;( But I do get your idea, thanks!

Comment: That does not make much of a difference. Just add the UIScrollView as subview of UIView and add the UIButton as well to the very same UIView object as subview. Both will share the same coordinate system. And scrolling and re-sizing the content view will not influence the button at all. Just make sure that the scroll view is added first so it is drawn first. Its subviews may be added even later.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add First Button on view Then Scroll View on View and please check in xib that button should not be in scrollview try this I think it is work for you.

Comment: If he adds the button first and then the scroll view then the scroll view ill overlap or even hide the button. At least, the button cannot be pressed.